# Android Studio cant process questionmark in String when using equals Method?

Tags: java, string, android-studio

Currently I try to learn about creating an android app and work through a Tutorial on it using android studio. 
So far, I've created two activites. 
The Main activity features a Plain Text Field and a Button. The other activity displays the input of the Plain Text Field when pressing the Button. 
The Tutorial ends here. 
For fun purpose, I want to change it to the second activity displaying certain text on one special input. Now the line to determine if input is equal to certain String looks like this:

```
String result = message.equals("foo?") ? "bar" : "wrong";
```

As long as I leave the Questionmark at the end of `"foo?"`, it sets `result` to `"wrong"`, although I intend it to be `bar`.
(With `message` being the content of the Plain Text Field from the Main Activity)

MCVE Attempt
Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE ="";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

/** Called when the user taps the Go Button */
public void sendMessage(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String message = editText.getText().toString(); //User puts in "foo?"
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}}
```

Second Activity (Showing the result)

```
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    String result = message.equals("foo?") ? "Bar" : "wrong"; //result is set to "wrong"
    textView.setText(result);
    //But "Bar" expected
}}
```

Changing userinput to `foo` instead of `foo?` and removing the questionmark in `.equals("foo?")` (to `.equals("foo")`) produces correct output. Hope thats enough

Comment: `String result = "foo?".equals("foo?") ? "bar" : "wrong";` is `bar`. So I have no idea what `message` is.

Comment: Message is what you write (with your phone) into the Plain Text Field in the first activity. If its `"foo?"`,`String result = message.equals("foo?) ? "bar" : "wrong";` `result`is `wrong` but if its `"foo"`, `String result = message.equals("foo") ? "bar" : "wrong"`,`result`is `bar`

Comment: Can't reproduce. `message` **isn't** what you think it is. Post a MCVE.

Comment: Hope thats everything required